# How to import models to a file that resides in the same folder as models.py?

Tags: python, django

I want to import models to `dashboards.py` file that is in the same folder as `models.py`:

```
#dashboards.py
from models import Listing, City
```

Running the file results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dashboards.py", line 6, in <module>
    from models import Listing, City #, ScrapingDate
  File "/home/bart/python_projects/javascript/models.py", line 19, in <module>
    class City(models.Model):
  File "/home/bart/python_projects/testenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 100, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/home/bart/python_projects/testenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 244, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/home/bart/python_projects/testenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 127, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

If I change to:

```
#dashboards.py
from .models import Listing, City
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dashboards.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .models import Listing, City #, ScrapingDate
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

I have also tried:

```
#dashboards.py
import django
django.setup()
from models import Listing, City
```

but:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dashboards.py", line 2, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "/home/bart/python_projects/testenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/home/bart/python_projects/testenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/bart/python_projects/testenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting LOGGING_CONFIG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: try `from app_name.models import model_name`

Comment: My app name is 'javascript' (stupid, I know). `from javascript.models import Listing, City` results in `no module named javascript` error.

Comment: @barciewicz Perhaps you just forgot to load the app in INSTALLED_APPS? Or maybe the list of INSTALLED_APPS has some errors, like missing comma and similar.

Comment: @Uros: No, `javascript` is in installed apps. The same imports work fine from within`views.py`, which sits at the same folder as `models.py` and `dashboards.py`...

Comment: Can you check your settings.py to see whether LOGGING_CONFIG and LOGGING are set with the correct values?